# A word encompassing both an IP address and the port used?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, if I were to connect to a service with the following address:

`68.146.63.194:3609`

Is there a word for this type of address? I suppose I could call it just a generic address but I was wondering if there was a word for this specific type of connection..

Comment: I think you would have found this a better fit for a more coding- or networking-related SE

Comment: Why was this closed as off-topic? Nothing in the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) suggests that there's anything wrong with this question, there's no information in the closure banner itself, and the only comment, from @simchona, doesn't provide a reason for closure, just notes that this might have fit better on another SE site - which isn't in itself a reason to close a question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is called "Authority". Please check the image below:

[image]

This picture has been taken from C# 4.0 in a Nutshell: The Definitive Reference Joseph Albahari

Comment: It should be noted that this is a highly technical term and this *specific* meaning is only known in a technical  context (granted: so are "host" and "port", but they are slightly more well-known).

Comment: @Unreason: the URI syntax (parts of which are visualized here) is defined in [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt). Actually, reading that RFC, it becomes clear that the Authority **contains** the user information (i.e. username + password, if they are encoded in the URI). That means the image above is *wrong*.

Comment: This term only works in the context of a URI. If you are just looking for the name of for example a UDP address/port combo, nobody will know what you are talking about.

Comment: Yeah, I've been building web-sites since the early '90s and I've never heard "authority" used that way.

Comment: See also these [visual examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Example_URIs) of URIs and their components.

Answer (score 11):

The correct answer is ***socket*** per the TCP/IP specification (RFC 793).

> To allow for many processes within a single Host to use TCP
>   communication facilities simultaneously, the TCP provides a set of
>   *addresses* or ***ports*** within each host.  *Concatenated with the network
>   and host addresses from the internet communication layer, this forms a
>   **socket**.*

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc793.html

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  The answer of "Authority" is really only relevant in the context of a URI.

Answer (score 6):

Is this any different from a socket address?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_socket